# How can I export just a single field from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Rather than export the entire table, that is, fname, lname, address, email, etc. how can I export JUST the email field to CSV or Excel?

Comment: What are you using to export the entire table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query the database and export the result.

Example:
`SELECT fname FROM users INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'` directly from mysql command line

or

`SELECT fname FROM users` and export the result of this query from your favorite mysql client

Comment: awesome.. thanks... what if i wanted to get crazy and add id>10,000 to get the most recent members or something... how can i do that? i tried the logical semantic language but got an error

Comment: Just add WHERE condition. 
    SELECT fname FROM users WHERE id > 10000 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'